# Left indent in tcblisting code

Tags: indentation, tcolorbox, tcblisting

In this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{myexample}{
  width=1.01\linewidth, sharp corners,%
  beforeafter skip=0.5\baselineskip,%
  sidebyside gap=2mm,%
  lower separated=false,middle=0pt,%
  colframe=red, enhanced, %
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!5!white},%
  righthand width=3cm,halign=left,%
  listing side text,%
  after=,%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Sample tcolorbox code}{A simple tcolorbox code}
\begin{myexample}
I don't know why the next text is left indent after the second line.
\end{myexample}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I don't know why the left indent in the text part. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beacuse, `tcolorbox` defines some default options for `listings`.

[image]

In particular, all code is suposed to be `LaTeX` and `tcblatex` style is applied. This style is defined in `tcblistings.code.tex` as

```
\lstdefinestyle{tcblatex}{language={[LaTeX]TeX},
     aboveskip={0\p@ \@plus 6\p@}, belowskip={0\p@ \@plus 6\p@},
     columns=fullflexible, keepspaces=true,
     breaklines=true, breakatwhitespace=true,
     basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, extendedchars=true, nolol,
     inputencoding=\kvtcb@listingencoding}
```

In this case `breaklines` is the option which produces the indention after first line. It is defined this way in `listings` package as you can see in next code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{myexample}{
  width=1.01\linewidth, sharp corners,%
  beforeafter skip=0.5\baselineskip,%
  sidebyside gap=2mm,%
  lower separated=false,middle=0pt,%
  colframe=red, enhanced, %
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!5!white},%
  righthand width=3cm,halign=left,%
  listing side text,%
  after=,%
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Sample tcolorbox code}{A simple tcolorbox code}
\begin{myexample}
I don't know why the next text is left indent after the second line.
\end{myexample}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines=true]
I don't know why the next text is left indent after the second line.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

First frame uses `tcblatex` style and second frame uses a regular `listings` listing with `breaklines` option. The result is:

[image]

The indention is defined with parameter `breakindent` in `listings` package, so you can always add

```
listing options={breaklines, breakindent=0pt}
```

to your `myexample` definition and eliminate the indention.

Comment: Ignasi: thanks for a wonderful explication and a perfect solution.